# Extending gem's strong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am trying to add custom attribute to a model provided by `Storytime` gem.

Here is the strong parameter method they provided: https://github.com/CultivateLabs/storytime/blob/master/app/controllers/storytime/dashboard/posts_controller.rb

```
      def post_params
        byebug
        post = @post || current_post_type.new(user: current_user)
        permitted_attrs = policy(post).permitted_attributes
        permitted_attrs = permitted_attrs.append(storytime_post_param_additions) if respond_to?(:storytime_post_param_additions)
        params.require(current_post_type.type_name.tableize.singularize.to_sym).permit(*permitted_attrs)
      end
```

Here is what I tried to implement.

```
Storytime::Dashboard::DashboardController.class_eval do
  before_action :parse_input, only: [:update]

  def storytime_post_param_additions
    attrs = [{:spree_product_ids => []}]
    attrs
  end

  def parse_input
    params[:spree_product_ids] = params[:spree_product_ids].split(',').map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

However, I have found that `append` put the array inside the `permitted_attrs` array, so I tried changing the gem code to use `concat` instead.

when I log the `permitted_attr` inside byebug with `concat` instead of `append` I got

```
[:title, :draft_content, :draft_version_id, :excerpt, :featured_media_id, :secondary_media_id, :slug, :published_at_date, :notifications_enabled, :published_at_time, {:tag_list=>[]}, :published, {:spree_product_ids=>[]}]
```

but when I try `params.permit(*permitted_attrs)` only my custom attribute was returned.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I name the input wrong (without the product_blog namespace), as a result, the params.require(:product_blog) causes everything outside the namespace to be removed from the hash. I change the view to and now it works.

```
<%= f.association :spree_products, input_html: { name: "#{@post.class.name.split('::').last.tableize.singularize}[spree_product_ids][]", class: 'chosen-select tags-input', multiple: true } %>
```